# building julia on cygwin, how to get stable version?

Tags: github, cygwin, julia

I am running Julia on cygwin. I followed the instructions at https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/README.windows.md , which tells to build it from sources, beginning with

```
git clone https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia.git
```

followed by a compile (which took about 2 hours).

But what I got was an unstable version (1.1.0-DEV.699). Is there any way to get the stable version of Julia, on cygwin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the current stable version:

```
git clone git://github.com/JuliaLang/julia.git
cd julia
git checkout v1.0.2
```

And now you are ready to build.

Comment: Before I saw your reply, I downloaded zip file from https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/tree/v1.0.2 , and proceeded from there, and that worked,

Comment: But a follow-up question: I think your recommendation should be added to the instructions at https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/README.windows.md . How is that done?

Comment: But that is under the general instructions, not the Windows instructions. The "Windows" heading at https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia simply says nothing more than "In order to build Julia on Windows, see README.windows." , which I followed to the letter. But again, thank you very much for pointing out my mistake,